# Sinatra error: NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0x007fa70444aef0>

Tags: activerecord, sqlite, sinatra

I'm creating a site using Sinatra and ActiveRecord.  Whenever I run my site I get the error

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading config.ru

NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<Class:0x007f8b646d8818>

/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
/Users/keturahwalters/Desktop/Projects/char_site/app.rb:20:in `<class:Contact>'
/Users/keturahwalters/Desktop/Projects/char_site/app.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:1:in `require'
config.ru:1:in `block in inner_app'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `inner_app'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in `eval'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in `inner_app'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:102:in `assemble_app'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:86:in `proceed_as_child'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:31:in `call!'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/favicon.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/static.rb:14:in `call'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:138:in `call'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/keturahwalters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

This is my app.rb

```ruby
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/activerecord"

set :database, "sqlite3:///events.db"

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates_uniqueness_of :first
    validates_presence_of :first

    validates_uniqueness_of :last
    validates_presence_of :last

    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates_presence_of :email

    get '/' do
        erb :index 
    end

    get '/weddings.erb' do
        erb :weddings
    end

    get '/birthdays.erb' do
        erb :birthdays
    end

    get '/anniversaries.erb' do
        erb :anniversaries
    end

    get '/about.erb' do
        erb :about
    end

    get '/contacts/new' do
        @contact = Contact.new
        erb :contact
    end

    post '/contacts' do
        @contact = Contact.new(params[:rabbit])
        if @contact.save
            status 201
            redirect '/' + @contact.id.to_s
        else
            status 400
            erb :contact
        end
    end

end
```

This is my config.ru

```ruby
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 2):

You've inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` but that's for database models.  Put your routes in a class that inherits from `Sinatra::Base` and make sure to `require 'sinatra/base'` too.